# Send mails MTA in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, email

I created a stored procedure for saving mails to the Microsoft SQL Server.
Then I need to send them using ASP.NET Web application. Can you tell me a way to do this?

It is good if this process is working automatically after saving mails to the database.

This is table format:

[image: Database table screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Database Setup:

Make sure you have a table in your SQL Server database to store the saved emails. This table should have columns for email content, sender, recipient, timestamp, etc.
Stored Procedure (SP) for Saving Emails:

You've already created an SP to save emails. Ensure it is properly storing the necessary information in the database.
Create ASP.NET Web Application:

Create a new ASP.NET web application project in Visual Studio.
Database Connection:

Set up a connection to your SQL Server database in your web application. You can use Entity Framework or ADO.NET for this.
Retrieve Emails:

Write a function or method to retrieve emails from the database. Use the stored procedure you created earlier.
Email Sending:

Use the SmtpClient class in C# to send emails. You'll need to provide the SMTP server details, sender's email credentials, and other necessary information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to process the database table and send emails automatically when the table is non-empty.

This is a task for a background process, not a web server. ASP.NET enables you to implement a web server that reactively handles HTTP requests.

Running in the background is a separate task and is more robustly done as a separate OS process, perhaps even on separate hardware.

There are lots of options in that space, depending on your deployment environment or requirements, such as Windows services, Azure functions, daemons, etc.